# Why is Vue changing the parent value from a child without emitting an event

Tags: vue.js

I am fairly new to Vue but doesn't this behavior completely contradict the design of props down, events up?

I have managed to stop it by using `Object.assign({}, this.test_object );` when initializing the value in `child-component` but shouldn't that be the default behaviour?

Here is some background.

I am trying to have a dirty state in a much larger application (Eg a value has changed so a user must save the data back to the database before continuing on their way)

I had an event being emitted, and caught by the parent but the code I had to test the value and init the dirty state was not running as the value had already been changed in the parent component.

```js
Vue.component( 'parent-component', {
  template: '#parent-component',
  data: function() {
    return {
      testObject: {
        val: 'Test Value'
      }
    }
  }
});

Vue.component( 'child-component', {
  template: '#child-component',
  props: {
    test_object: Object
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      child_object: this.test_object
    }
  }
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="parent-component">
    <div>
        <child-component :test_object="testObject"></child-component>
        
        <p>This is in the parent component</p>
        <p><code>testObject.val = {{testObject.val}}</code></p>
        
    </div>
</script>
  
<script type="text/x-template" id="child-component">
    <div>
        <label for="html_input">HTML Input</label>
        <input style="border:1px solid #CCC; display:block;" type="text" name="html_input" v-model="child_object.val" />
    </div>
</script>

<div id="app">
  <parent-component></parent-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of `v-model` is a very deceptive thing. If you are not careful, you might end-up mutating data that doesn't belong to your component. In your case, you are accidentally passing read-only props directly to the `v-model`. It doesn't know if it is a `prop` or a local component state.

What you are doing is the right solution but considering one-way/unidirectional data flow in mind, we can rewrite this example in more explicit and elegant fashion:

Your component definition would be:

```
Vue.component( 'parent-component', {
  template: '#parent-component',
  data: function() {
    return {
      testObject: {
        val: 'Test Value'
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    // Added this method to listen for input event changes
    onChange(newValue) {
      this.testObject.val = newValue;

      // Or if you favor immutability
      // this.testObject = {
      //   ...this.testObject,
      //   val: newValue
      // };
    }
  }
});
```

Your templates should be:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="parent-component">
  <div>
    <child-component :test_object="testObject"
      @inputChange="onChange"></child-component>
      
    <p>This is in the parent component</p>
    <p><code>testObject.val = {{testObject.val}}</code></p>
      
  </div>
</script>

<!-- Instead of v-model, you can use :value and @input binding. -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="child-component">
  <div>
    <label for="html_input">HTML Input</label>
    <input type="text" name="html_input"
      :value="test_object.val"
      @input="$emit('inputChange', $event.target.value)" />
  </div>
</script>
```

Key things to note:

- When using v-model, ensure that you are strictly working on a local value/data of the component. By no means, it should be referenced copy of external prop.
- A custom form-like component can be readily converted into the one that can work with `v-model` provided you accept current value as `:value` prop and event as `@input`. `v-model` will just [work out of the box](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model).
- Any modification to the value should happen in the same component.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @HarshalPatil so are you saying that initializing the child object with `Object.assign({}, this.test_object );` is the correct way of creating a local object that will not be mutated out of the current component ?

Comment: @BenCasey, definitely not. `Object.assign` will work in a current situation but not a great general purpose solution. Many things will go wrong. Imagine, `testObject` as an async value. You would end up setting watcher for this prop. `testObject` could be deeply nested and so on. The one I suggested is a generic pattern for unidirectional data architectures. It applies to Vue, React, Angular, Elm, etc.